# bet365/soap package(s) ignores namespace-prefix on elements of type "sequence"

Tags: soap, xml-parsing, wsdl, erlang

I am using the following erlang package to work with some WSDL-Services: `https://github.com/bet365/soap`.

The most part is working fine! But my WSDL-service expects that elements of type `sequence` (including all sub-elements) have an existing namespace-prefix in the XML. The problem is that the `bet365/soap` is ignoring this when I try to request with the generated client.

Please look at my simple examples:

**What is needed:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:s:v2">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:getArticles>
         <client>my-client</client>
         <articleRequest Id="99999">

            <!-- List 1 to 50 elements:-->
            <urn:article>
               <urn:id>1234</urn:id >
               <urn:quantity>4</urn:quantity >
            </urn:article >

         </articleRequest >
      </urn:getArticles >
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**What is generated by the `bet365/soap`:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:s:v2">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:getArticles>
         <client>my-client</client>
         <articleRequest Id="99999">

            <!-- List 1 to 50 elements:-->
            <article>
               <id>1234</id >
               <quantity>4</quantity >
            </article >

         </articleRequest >
      </urn:getArticles >
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone help? Maybe there is an option I can pass to `bet365/soap` to add and use the missing `namespace` prefix?

Maybe there is a code change needed in the `bet365/soap` package?

Many thanks!